# java ant run command - can not find lib jars

Tags: java, ant, configuration, compilation

My ant build file looks like this:

```
<project name="Algorithm" basedir="." default="main">

<property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>

<property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
<property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>

<property name="main-class"  value="ye.tian.Main"/>

<property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>

<property name="lib.dir"     value="lib"/>

<path id="myclasspath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
</path>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="myclasspath"/>
</target>

<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" classpathref="myclasspath" fork="true"/>
</target>
```

My project structure is: root folder with two folders inside named src and lib. Lib contains all the jar libraries and src - packages with java files.

Running the `ant run` gives an error:

```
run:
 [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference
```

[image: My libs folder looks like this:]

Which i understand can not find library jars named Jackson which are under lib folder... My linking must be wrong. Any advice?

Thank!

UPDATE: Updated build.xml file with the suggestion from @AR.3 still the same issue

Comment: You're sure you have jackson-core.jar inside lib folder ?

Comment: @AnonymousUser i have attached screenshot of my lib folder contents.

Comment: Are you able to find this path under your jackson-core-2.8.5 jar? if yes then make sure that your lib folder is being read correctly by ant .. I saw that you're pointing to it as ./lib unlike src

Comment: @AnonymousUser i have updated the question with your suggestion and still the same issue.

Comment: You might want to run ant with the `-v` (verbose) option.  You’ll get a great deal of output, but there is a good chance that it will show which .jar files are in the classpath.

Comment: @VGR thanks for the suggestion i have done that before and i could see all the jar files under the classpath option when running java in a fashion: -classpath path1_jar:path2_jar:path3_jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make all the paths in all the properties absolute (by prefixing `src.dir`, `build.dir` and `lib.dir` with `${basedir}/`). Thus you don't have to rely on working directory. `<java>` task you run in `run` target might use `${jar.dir}` as a working directory and your classpath (which is resolved as a relative path) would point to non-existing `build/jar/lib/*.jar`.

```
<property name="src.dir"     value="${basedir}/src"/>
<property name="build.dir"   value="${basedir}/build"/>
<property name="lib.dir"     value="${basedir}/lib"/>

<property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
<property name="main-class"  value="ye.tian.Main"/>
<property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>
```